# mySQL/Sequelize - how to query to get data whose field is empty array

Tags: mysql, sql, orm, sequelize.js

My http request will return below data:
It returns below data:

Users.js

```
{
    {
       ...
       friends:[]
    },
    {
       ...
       friends:[{id:xxx,...},...]
    },
    {
       ...
       friends:[]
    },
}
```

If I want to use query to get all data whose friends array is [],
should I do below query.
select * from users where (what should I write here)

Answer (score 1):

If `friends` is a direct column in your database is `JSON` array. You can use [`JSON_LENGTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-attribute-functions.html#function_json-length) to find out the length of array.

```
SELECT JSON_LENGTH('[1, 2, {"a": 3}]'); // Output: 3
SELECT JSON_LENGTH('[]'); // Output: 0
```

You can use same concept to get data from your database.

```
select * 
FROM users 
WHERE JSON_LENGTH(friends) = 0;
```

If you've nested JSON and one of key is `friends` in that json for given column(`data`) then your query would be like using [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains)

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(data, JSON_ARRAY(), '$.friends') -- To check do we have `friends` as key in that json
  and JSON_LENGTH(data, '$.friends') = 0;  -- To check whether it is empty array.
```

Now you can convert it to sequelize query. One of the way you can use is

```
Model.findAll({
   where: {
       [Op.and]: [
           Sequelize.literal('RAW SQL STATEMENT WHICH WONT BE ESCAPED!!!')
       ]
   }
})
```

Make sure to update `Model` with your `user` model and query.